# Excel formula to calculate based on another field's contents

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

[image]

What I want to achieve is, to create a universal formula for Bob, George, Charles, to calculate
their balance based on "Affects balance" field.

So in the example below results would be following:

```
C3: 400, D3: 150, E3: 240, F3: 10 //(Because in/out field affects only Bob's balance)
C4: 280, D4: 90, E3: 240, F3: -50 //(Because in/out field affectS Bob's and Charles's balance equally)
```

Please take a look at this example sheets:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NggjOiebkfUguugtw6lrzBy11F5fVJdree_WG0H3jVA/edit#gid=0

I can't figure out how would be the formula. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is insufficiently specific. I don't know how @basic figured out what you wanted without your saying it, but please [edit] your question to include details on how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try following formula:

```
=D2+IFERROR((SEARCH(D$1,$B3)>0)*($A3/(LEN($B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B3,",",""))+1)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: OH! The delta is split across however many users are in the "affects" field for that change record. I didn't understand until I saw your answer. Good job. I've deleted mine.